# Witcher 3 force static screen instead of narrator

Tags: pc, the-witcher-3

I'm tired to hear the same story every time the load screen comes up.

How can I make it show a static screen when loading the scenario instead of the narrator saying the exact same script over and over again!

Comment: The screen does change as you move through the main quests.

Comment: @greg-449, Yes, it changes, but it takes a lot of time to change. And now I am at the end of the game, just Isle of Mist mission to finish, and I am trying to level up by doing secondary missions and witcher contract and the same screen with the same story keeps showing over and over again. It is freaking annoying!

Comment: If you find the narration annoying, you can hit the space bar to skip it (I play on the PC, maybe on consoles it is different?)

Comment: I play on pc too. Space bar does not skip load screen narrator for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mod called [Disable Intro and storybook videos](http://www.nexusmods.com/witcher3/mods/66/) available that disables the loading screen videos.

Comment: OMG!!!! I can't believe that exist! Thank you very much! As soon I get home from work I will test it!

Comment: Is this work on PS4?

Comment: @rahul Sorry but PC only.

Comment: @LoreFriendly yeah i have checked in ps4 No Option :(

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to skip. This basically **is** the loading screen. The loading screen after this narration is merely the closing of the loading part (and it instantly vanishes, at least for me).